# RabbitMq with Mqqt protocol with ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, rabbitmq, mqtt

I'm using RabbitMq 3.6.6 with paho.mqttv3 protocol 
my simple code like

```
int max_connections =400000;
String broker = "tcp://xxx.xxx.x.xx:1883";
String clientId = "Publisher";
String content="Hii";
int qos=1;
String topic="Cluster";


MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
MqttClient sampleClient[] = new MqttClient[max_connections];

Thread t[] = new Thread[max_connections];
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setCleanSession(true);

for (int i = 0; i < max_connections; i++) {
    try {
        sampleClient[i] = new MqttClient(broker, clientId + "" + i, persistence);
        sampleClient[i].connect(connOpts);
    } catch (MqttException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 
}
```

I'm Getting Exception Like :

> Exception in thread "MQTT Con: Publisher2919"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread    at
>   java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)   at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsSender.start(CommsSender.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:654)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My system RAM is 8 GB with Corei5 Processor.

> I have also try in Windows PC in that same Error but Its Upto 7k
>   Connection

```
so any OS level Configuration in Ubuntu to make more Connection?
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. Trying to create 400,000 threads is not really a realistic thing to do.

I assume you are trying to load test your MQTT broker, you would do better looking at something like JMeter from Apache which can run in distributed mode and use multiple machines to generate very high levels of load.

Comment: Thanks Hardlib for your quick Response, Yes I aggree with you for I'm trying to test multi connection .. but Mqtt broker create connection up 3k only .....is it possible to create more than this ??

Comment: The error message is about the amount of memory used by each thread, at 3000 it has consumed more memory than either your machine has or any given process is allowed to have by the OS

Comment: yes it's problem with memory for this i tried to increase 'high watermark' in RabbitMq Config file but still its not able to connect more than 3000 connection.as you said run with Distribute for the same how can I get this ?

Comment: The error is with the client, not the broker. Changing settings on the broker won't do anything

Comment: ok, any Idea for this change how its possible to create on Demand connection?